# Converting the Clifford Attractor equation into python to animate it in blender 2.8

Tags: python, animation, scripting, mathematics

I'm trying to **re-create** and **animate** a "Whispy Clifford Attractors" this  http://paulbourke.net/fractals/clifford/5.jpg  from this site http://paulbourke.net/fractals/clifford/
[image: <image>]

I can create the equations and animate the `a` variable in Octave / Matlab (but as you can see it's not a great image see animated gif below).

[image: <Octave animation>]  I'm having trouble re-creating and animating the image in Bender 2.8

I've adapted some python code but I'm having trouble with the math syntax to get it to work in Blender 2.8

```
Clifford formula
xn+1 = sin(a*yn) + c cos(a*xn)
yn+1 = sin(b*xn) + d cos(b*yn)
where a, b, c, d are variables that define each attractor.
```

When I run my script and click on -Add- -Curve- -Test Attactors- -Lorenz- This one works [image: <insert animation>]

When I click on *-Add- -Curve- -Test Attactors- -Clifford-* I get a single curve line. [image: <insert image>]

I believe the issue is in these lines but I'm not sure how to fix it.  I tried different `for` and `while` loops but no luck.

```
def iterate(self, x, y, z):

    #while itr < 100:
    #for i in range (10): 
      #add for loop find out npoints in while loop
    dx = math.sin(self.a*y) + self.c*math.cos(self.a*x)
    dy = math.sin(self.b*x) + self.d*math.cos(self.b*y)
    dz = math.sin(self.e*x) + self.f*math.cos(self.e*z)
    return (dx, dy, dz)
```

Here's the entire python code:

```
import bpy
import math

from bpy.props import BoolProperty
from bpy.props import FloatProperty
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from bpy.props import IntProperty

#print(IndentationError().msg)


bl_info = {
  "author": "rt_and_mike.tyka@gmail.com",
  "blender": (2, 80, 0),
  "category": "Add Curve",
  "description": "Creates a strange attractor curve",
  "location": "View3D > Add > Curve > Attractors",
  "name": "Test Attractors",
  "version": (0, 1),
  "warning": "",
  "wiki_url": ""
}

def get_prop(cls, name, default):
  return bpy.props.FloatProperty(attr=cls + "_" + name,
                                 name=name,
                                 description="",
                                 default=default)

def get_int_prop(cls, name, default):
  return bpy.props.IntProperty(attr=cls + "_" + name,
                                 name=name,
                                 description="",
                                 default=default)
def get_npoints(default=10000):
  return IntProperty(attr="npoints",
                     name="Vertices",
                     description="",
                     min=1, soft_min=1, default=default)

class Object_OT_Attractor(bpy.types.Operator):
  bl_idname= "object.attractor"
  bl_label= "Label Attractor"
  view_align= BoolProperty(name="Align to View",default=False)
  location= FloatVectorProperty(name="Location",subtype="TRANSLATION")
  rotation= FloatVectorProperty(name="Rotation",subtype="EULER")

  def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(self, "npoints", text="Vertices")

    col = layout.column(align=True)
    for param in self.params:
          col.prop(self, param, text=param)

    col2 = layout.column(align=True)
    col2.prop(self, "x", text="x")
    col2.prop(self, "y", text="y")
    col2.prop(self, "z", text="z")
    col2.prop(self, "dt", text="dt")


  def execute(self, context):
    curvedata = bpy.data.curves.new(name="Curve", type="CURVE")
    curvedata.dimensions = "3D"

    objectdata = bpy.data.objects.new("ObjCurve", curvedata)
    objectdata.location = (0,0,0) 
    #bpy.context.scene.objects.link(objectdata)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(objectdata)

    polyline = curvedata.splines.new("POLY")
    polyline.points.add(self.npoints-1)

    x = self.x
    y = self.y
    z = self.z

    n = 0
    while n < self.npoints:
      dx, dy, dz = self.iterate(x, y, z)
      x = x + self.dt * dx
      y = y + self.dt * dy
      z = z + self.dt * dz
      polyline.points[n].co = (x,y,z,math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz))
      n += 1

    return {"FINISHED"}

class CliffordAttractor(Object_OT_Attractor):
  bl_idname = "curve.clifford_attractor_add"
  bl_label = "Clifford Attractor"
  bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

  npoints = get_npoints()
  params = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
  a= get_prop("clifford", "a", -1.24458)
  b= get_prop("clifford", "b", -1.25191)
  c= get_prop("clifford", "c", -1.815908)
  d= get_prop("clifford", "d", -1.90866)
  e= get_prop("clifford", "e", -0.20)
  f= get_prop("clifford", "f",  0.50)

  x= get_prop("clifford", "x",   0.10)
  y= get_prop("clifford", "y",   0.00)
  z= get_prop("clifford", "z",   0.00)
  dt= get_prop("clifford", "dt", 0.01)


  def iterate(self, x, y, z):
    #global itr
    #while itr < 100:
    #for i in range (10): 
      #add for loop find out npoints in while loop
    dx = math.sin(self.a*y) + self.c*math.cos(self.a*x)
    dy = math.sin(self.b*x) + self.d*math.cos(self.b*y)
    dz = math.sin(self.e*x) + self.f*math.cos(self.e*z)
    return (dx, dy, dz)

class LorenzAttractor(Object_OT_Attractor):
  bl_idname = "curve.lorenz_attractor_add"
  bl_label = "Lorenz Attractor"
  bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

  npoints = get_npoints()
  params = ["a", "b", "c"]
  a = get_prop("lorenz", "a",  10.00)
  b = get_prop("lorenz", "b",  28.00)
  c = get_prop("lorenz", "c",  (8/3))

  x = get_prop("lorenz", "x",   0.10)
  y = get_prop("lorenz", "y",   0.00)
  z = get_prop("lorenz", "z",   0.00)
  dt = get_prop("lorenz", "dt", 0.01)

  def iterate(self, x, y, z):
    dx = self.a * (y - x)
    dy = (x * (self.b - z) - y)
    dz = (x * y - self.c * z)
    return (dx, dy, dz)



class Menu_MT_AttractorMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
  #bl_idname = "INFO_MT_curve_attractor_add"
  bl_idname= "menu.attractormenu"
  bl_label= "Test Attractors"

  def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator_context = "INVOKE_REGION_WIN"
    #layout.label(text="Hello First Menu!", icon='WORLD_DATA')

    layout.operator("curve.clifford_attractor_add", text="Clifford")
    layout.operator("curve.lorenz_attractor_add",text="Lorenz")

def menu_func(self, context):
  #self.layout.menu("INFO_MT_curve_attractor_add", icon="PLUGIN")
  self.layout.menu(Menu_MT_AttractorMenu.bl_idname, icon="PLUGIN")
  #self.layout.operator(AttractorMenu.bl_idname)


#needed as workaround
bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_curve_add.append(menu_func)

#All classes used  
classes = (
            Object_OT_Attractor,
            Menu_MT_AttractorMenu,
            LorenzAttractor,
            CliffordAttractor,
          )

#Register and unregister all classes  
register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)


# This allows you to run the script directly from Blender's Text editor
# to test the add-on without having to install it.
if __name__ == "__main__":
  register()
```

Comment: At least, should not be "x = x + self.dt * dx" but "x = self.dt * dx". Nonetheless this is not enough to have a nice curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some little enhancements in *'Object_OT_Attractor'*.

Mainly the issue was due to `x = x + ...` instead of `x = ...`. So have changed that but that means you'll have to adapt Lorenz the same way.

Have also used a Bezier curve with *'AUTOMATIC'* handle type.

```
  def execute(self, context):
    curvedata = bpy.data.curves.new(name="Curve", type='CURVE')
    curvedata.dimensions = '3D'

    objectdata = bpy.data.objects.new("ObjCurve", curvedata)
    objectdata.location = (0,0,0) 

    # Changed to Bezier
    polyline = curvedata.splines.new('BEZIER')
    polyline.bezier_points.add(self.npoints-1)

    x = self.x
    y = self.y
    z = self.z

    n = 0
    while n < self.npoints:
      dx, dy, dz = self.iterate(x, y, z)
      # No more x = x +
      x = self.dt * dx
      y = self.dt * dy
      z = self.dt * dz
      polyline.bezier_points[n].co = (x,y,z)
      n += 1

    context.scene.collection.objects.link(objectdata)
    # Set object active
    objectdata.select_set( True )
    context.view_layer.objects.active = objectdata
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.curve.select_all(action='SELECT')
    # Automatic handle type
    bpy.ops.curve.handle_type_set(type='AUTOMATIC')
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

    return {"FINISHED"}
```

Note: I've used bpy.ops to set handle type as setting it directly in data is too slow.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I replaced my  `def execute` in the `Object_OT_Attractor`  with yours but when I run the script and click on the `Clifford` or the `Lorenz` option the plugin works but the image is a extremely small single line curve hook similar to before.  Nothing like your cool animated image.

Comment: I've rearranged a, b, c, d, e, f that may be the cause...

Comment: another way to get wispy effect https://youtu.be/rtPzXrZ23k0

Comment: 2nd way to get wispy effect https://youtu.be/CrOboutVHH8